# jQuery Explode Effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-effects

With **jQuery UI**, there is an [amazing explode effect](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Explode). I wonder how they have created it.

I am looking for implementation of that; how to create that effect without resorting to **jQuery UI** and use jQuery alone for that effect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The source code is available on GitHub.](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.effect-explode.js)